# Unexpected JSON.stringify behavior with arrays on specific website

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm running JSON3 library which fails because for some reason JSON.stringify return different results on specific website, unfortunately the page is behind login but iv'e provided images.

Home page of 'concursolutions.com' portal, if someone have loggin.

Similarities -

1. Both functions use the 'native function' (as shown in the image)
2. Both pages use HTML5 doctype (ie.  )
3. both tested on chrome 59

What else should I check? im out of ideas

The code I used:

```
JSON.stringify({'a':[1, 2]}, undefined, 1)
```

**The unexpected behavior**
[image]

**The expected behavior**

[image]

Comment: It isn't wrong :|

Comment: What browser are you using? Double check input value. Paste it to us. Maybe it's actually `"[1, 2]"`? Or already json encoded value?

Comment: Same function return different results, how is that now wrong?

Comment: Do not post [image of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Milan Chheda - It's spacial circumstances, I want to show that the 'JSON.stringify' was not manipulated before!

Comment: @Justinas it's screenshot of Chrome-devtools, you can see it's not a string.

Comment: Any reason for voting CLOSE? hint of what is wrong will be better then just voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly found the answer, The problem is a BUG in 'prototype.js' version 1.6.1.0

prototype.js library modify/override lots of 'native' functions.

prototype add's toJSON function to arrays, that cause the JSON.stingify to get that value instead of the original value.

More info about 'toJSON' behavior

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior